# Create an access dropdown based on a many to many relationship

Tags: ms-access, combobox, many-to-many

I have a database which holds data about audio files.
The main three tables are Volume, Author, and VolumeWithAuthor. A volume can have multiple authors, and an author multiple volumes, so they each have a many to one relationship with the VolumeWithAuthor table.

```
They look like this:  
   Volume:  
      ID- set to autonumber  
      Volume- the name of each file   
   Author:  
      AuthID- autonumber  
      AuthName- a string with the author name  
      AuthTitle- Dr., Mr. or Mrs., etc.

They are joined on the VolumeWithAuthor:
      ID- autonumber
      Volume- linked to Volume.Volume
      AuthID - linked to Author.AuthID
```

I have a form linked to the Volume table. Users need to be able to input authors on that form. So the dropdown has to display the entries  from Author.AuthName, and then create a new entry in VolumeWithAuthor.
I created a subform that displays all of the authors for each recording, but I can't work out how to add a dropdown.

I think this is something that is probably fairly basic, but I didn't see any similar questions that had answers that worked for me.
Thanks

Comment: Did you mean need to input authors to VolumeWithAuthor? Advise not to use exact same field name in multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just a typo in your narrative, but need to select authors to VolumeWithAuthor, not Volume.

Options for data entry:

1. main form bound to Volume and subform bound to VolumeWithAuthor with a combobox to select author
2. main form bound to Author and subform bound to VolumeWithAuthor with a combobox to select volume
3. one form bound to VolumnWithAuthor with comboboxes to select volume and author

Use combobox Not in List event to add new author or volume to those tables on-the-fly during data entry.