# ACCESS VBA HELP - Entering Data into Junction Table through MultiValuedField on Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

is there a way I can find the number of selections that have been made in a multivalued field on a form? I want to take the data from a multivalued field, and for every check that has been made, make a new entry in my Junction table for that song. Does that make sense? For [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/900UH.png), in this situation, the code would see that there were two selections, and would make an entry using the number (The Artist ID) under the SongID of the form record it was entered under into the Junction Table. Thanks!

Comment: What is purpose of this exercise? Are you trying to eliminate multi-value field?

Comment: I think it is fine to keep the Multi Valued Field now that I have had a closer look (Unless there is a better solution). What code can I use to look at the selections made, and make an entry in my Junction Table accordingly, with the Artist_ID and the Song_ID the selection was made under? I am new to Access and Vba so I am still thinking in simple python. Basically what I want to do is take the entries in the MVF and add them to the Junction Table, essentially automating the Junction Table Entry. The purpose of this excersise is to automate the Junction Table Entry, in the Form.

Comment: Data in multi-value field and data in junction table is storing data in two places. This is a bizarre design. For many-to-many relationship conventional data entry arrangement options review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69169018/create-an-access-dropdown-based-on-a-many-to-many-relationship/69169388#69169388

Comment: Hi June, I used this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ys-VCUZ0h7c . I have the subform in, but when I go to select an artist, I get the Microsoft Error Noise, I think you know the one, but no pop up dialogue box. What's the problem? I saw that he originally had that problem, and then he went and set a new default value. The thing is, I only have one field in the table, so I don't know what the problem is? How can I attach my database so you can see it?

Comment: I think the problem is that access needs an entry for the song into the Junction Table as well as the Artist, I thought the Master Child Thing would work, I am not sure why it is not. I have done some testing, and added the field for the Song_ID, and did the Master Child thing again. The Song field is not filling with the ID of the current song being entered. Could I zip the database and send a google drive link? Here is a Drive LInk: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s4A8WekD6JOF_XT8RGw1vYVfk3lLNsh9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: SO does not support attaching files and discourages links to downloads. SO model is to include in question all info needed to analyze issue. There are other forums that do allow attaching files. Even if link is provided, many refuse to download from outside forum.

Comment: That YouTube is a bad example of building form/subform. Did you review link I provided in earlier comment? I took a chance and tried to download your file. It doesn't.

Comment: I did cheat and download the db.  Making a faster data-entry form is a common problem.  Easier and better to not use a multi-valued field use junction tables(JT).  replace band members comma separated string in Bands with JT BandsArtists.  then I suggest trying the auto forms for bands, artists, bandsartists.  Once you have BandsArtists you can use vba to do Multiple the multiple Insert in the Form for SongsArtists.  see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70175837/populating-multiple-fields-in-subform-using-combobox-and-afterupdate-event-prodc/70184495#70184495

Comment: Hi June, I looked at the post you linked, but it didn't really give me a full understanding of how I was meant to actually do what the answerer said. "Use combobox Not in List event to add new author or volume to those tables on-the-fly during data entry." This in particular confused me. Secondly, What would the subform be; a creation of the Junction Table? A form with a combo box for artist? In regards to mazoula's comment, there are some songwriter's (Artists) who wrote some songs, but are not in any of the bands, such as Chuck Berry. This would be a problem for your solution.